# Square elements of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does every element of an abelian group $G$ have to be a square (ie for $g \in G$, $x = g^2$) if every element of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ and every element of the factor group $G/H$ is square? Since the elements modded out by $H$ are regained in the union of the factor group with $H$, I expect that it must be true, but that is not very rigorous and I am struggling to make it so.

Comment: This does follow from the snake lemma $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  You should have posted that snake lemma solution, rather than the one you wrote.  :P

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in G$. Then $xH$ is a square in $G/H$, so $xH=y^2H$, that is
$x=y^2h$ with $h\in H$. So $h$ is a square: $h=k^2$ and then $x=y^2k^2$
etc.

Comment: How does that prove that any/every element of $G$ is a square? It sounds like it just proves that every element in $H$ is a square which we already knew.

Comment: @drewjoe What part do you not understand? Since $G$ is abelian, $x=y^2k^2=(yk)^2$, so it is a square. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $G$, every element of $G$ is a square.

Comment: Why is $xH$ necessarily a square in $G/H$?

Comment: @drewjoe that's **your** hypothesis.